# Converting date string to/from date of different locale

Tags: swift

Taking the Japanese locale for example,

converting `2017-06-08T14:41:56+0000` to a format `EEEE, MMM d, yyyy` under the locale `ja` will give:

`木曜日, 6月 8, 2017`

but converting `木曜日, 6月 8, 2017` to a date object using the format `EEEE, MMM d, yyyy` and locale does not work.

Is there a way to handle date/time string conversions for unique locales?

Comment: Your dateFormat only contains weekday, month, day of month and year. How do you expect to be able to convert back to a date that contains hours, minutes and seconds as well? To make it more clear, in a US locale the date string would be "Thursday, Jun 8, 2017". No time information included.

Comment: My bad i should not have copied paste the whole string...i edit the question. Thanks